# Stuck on the boot screen with locked bootloader - Pixel 6

Tags: boot-loop, bootloader, google-pixel

I was trying to flash a custom ROM on my phone (Pixel 6) and something went wrong. i was following the instructions on screen and the last one was to lock the bootloader which I did. Now the phone seems to be stuck in the boot loop (I keep getting the google screen) when I start. On the boot screen I am unable to use the recovery or rescue mode, they bring me back to the boot screen. I'm very concerned about what to do now. Can someone please help!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a PC?

You may be able to get into the phone via [ADB](https://www.xda-developers.com/install-adb-windows-macos-linux/), that you can install to your PC from the Android SDK Platform Tools ZIP file for Windows, Linux, et cetera

There is a guide on the [XDA forum](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/ultimate-guide-for-bootloop-recovery-noob-friendly.2426426/) to help you.

1st on the list is to get to recovery via ADB via "adb reboot recovery"